# Magento: how to manually customer account activation

Tags: php, magento, plugins

I'm developing a magento theme; but my customer asked me a particular modification: he wants to confirm manually the users registration.
How can I achieve this? is there a plugin or I have to do this with an hacking the core code? Advice?
thanks

Comment: This can actually be a simple module that can be created and reused. It might also help one learn Magento development along the way. I would create a module to listen for user registration events. In the config.xml for the module, I would declare my observer and handler method for the event. Then I would code my observer model. When the user registers, my observer will be notified and have its handler function executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extension for it:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/489/customer-activation

Answer (score 3):

The extension that [clockworkgeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471559/clockworkgeek) posted is great, but it isn't currently in MagentoConnect. So, here is the github link: https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation